# Get Elements from Primefaces picklist

Tags: primefaces

i trie to store from a primefaces picklist the elements fro both lists into my database, but that dosen't work.

Here's my code:

```
private DualListModel<Objekt> verfuegbar;
private List<Objekt> white;
private List<Objekt> black;
[...]
public void speichern() {
    List<Objekt> listeWhite = white;
    List<Objekt> listeBlack = black;

    //This also not working
    // List<Objekt> listeWhite = verfuegbar.getSource();
    // List<Objekt> listeBlack = verfuegbar.getTarget();

    for (Objekt oW : listeWhite) {
        oW.setBw(1);
        objektDAO.aendern(oW);

    }

    for (Objekt oB : listeWhite) {
        oB.setBw(0);
        objektDAO.aendern(oB);

    }
    white = objektDAO.alleObjekteWhite();
    black = objektDAO.alleObjekteBlack();

    verfuegbar = new DualListModel<Objekt>(white, black);

    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Gespeichert", "Alle Daten wurden gesichert");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}

@PostConstruct
private void init() {

    // Liste füllen
    white = objektDAO.alleObjekteWhite();
    black = objektDAO.alleObjekteBlack();

    verfuegbar = new DualListModel<Objekt>(white, black);

    if (white.size() > 0 || black.size() > 0) {
        inhaltInListe = true;
    }
}
[...]
//getter and setter
```

The Method "alleObjekteWhite()" and "alleObjekteBlack()" in the init() gets the elements from my database.

So my Problem is now, that the listeWhite and listeBlack are empty so nothing is changed in the speichern-Method.

Comment: Primefaces showcase works, find the differences

Answer (score 0):

No i got the solution. The mistake was, that i haven't set the Scope. So the default Scope was RequestScope which was false. I've set it to SessionScope and it works!
Thanks